# C++. Передача указателя на методы потомка в родительский класс

Tags: c++, классы, функции, указатели, наследование

```
class A {
    std::vector<Method> Methods;
    void DoSomething(int methodNo, Arg1* arg1, Arg2* arg2) {
        (this->*(Methods[methodNo]))(arg1, arg2);
    }
}

class B : public A{
    B() {
        Methods.push_back(&B::Something);
    }

    Something(Arg1* arg1, Arg2* arg2) { }
}
```

Необходимо вызывать методы потомка из методов родителя, что-то вроде псевдокода выше. Как это лучше реализовать?

Родитель является адаптером к другому API, хочется выделить потомка для реализации конкретных экземпляров функций.

Comment: защищённый виртуальный метод, не?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в самый раз...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас уже практически все сделано.

Для *вызова* методов потомка через указатель на метод родителя никаких преобразований не надо. У вас в классе `A` все уже сделано правильно. Классу `A` ничего не нужно знать ни о каких наследниках, при условии, что вы сами гарантируете правильность такого вызова *в момент вызова*, *на уровне динамического типа объекта*.

Указатели на методы классов в С++ **контравариантны**. Это означает, что язык С++ гарантирует вам, что вы можете *неявно* преобразовывать указатели на методы вниз по иерархии и *явно*, при помощи `static_cast`, преобразовывать такие указатели вверх по иерархии (т.е. указатель на метод класса-наследника `Derived` к типу указателя на метод предка `Base`). (Сравните с **ковариантными** указателями на объекты, у которых все наоборот.)

После `static_cast`-преобразования вверх по иерархии вы можете затем спокойно вызвать указуемый метод класса `Derived`, при условии, что *динамический тип* объекта, использованного в вызове является "правильным" (т.е. это именно `Derived` или какой-то тип унаследованный от `Derivеd`). То есть вызов можно осуществлять, например, через указатель на класс `Base`, при условии, что этот указатель фактически указывает на объект `Derived`.

```
struct Base {};

struct Derived : Base { 
  void foo() { std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; } 
};    

struct DerivedDerived : Derived { 
  void foo() { std::cout << "Um..." << std::endl; } 
};

struct Derived2 : Base { 
  void foo() { std::cout << "Goodbye World!" << std::endl; } 
};

struct Independent { 
  void foo() { std::cout << "Huh?" << std::endl; } 
};

int main()
{
   Derived d;
   DerivedDerived dd;
   Derived2 d2;

   void (Base::*pfoo)() = static_cast<void (Base::*)()>(&Derived::foo);
   // Корректное преобразование, поддерживается `static_cast`

   Base *b = &d;
   (b->*pfoo)(); 
   // Корректное выражение, корректный вызов `d.foo()`

   (d.*pfoo)();
   // Корректное выражение, корректный вызов `d.foo()`

   b = &dd; 
   (b->*pfoo)(); 
   // Корректное выражение, корректный вызов `dd.Derived::foo()`

   (dd.*pfoo)();
   // Корректное выражение, корректный вызов `dd.Derived::foo()`

   b = &d2; 
   (b->*pfoo)(); 
   // Корректное выражение, некорректный вызов - поведение не определено

   (d2.*pfoo)();
   // Корректное выражение, некорректный вызов - поведение не определено

   Independent i;
   (i.*pfoo)();
   // Некорректное выражение, ошибка компиляции

   pfoo = static_cast<void (Base::*)()>(&Independent::foo);
   // Некорректное преобразование, не поддерживается `static_cast`,
   // ошибка компиляции
}
```

Через этот механизм язык С++ предоставляет вам возможность некоторой "ручной" реализации полиморфизма, в котором класс-предок ничего не знает о классах-потомках.

Таким образом, явное приведение типа в вашем случае нужно, но именно и только в потомке: для приведении типа указателя на метод `B` к типу указателя на метод `A` при *заполнении* вашего вектора. То есть все, что нужно исправить в вашем коде, это

```
Methods.push_back(static_cast<Method>(&B::Something));
```

При желании вы можете завести в базовом классе метод

```
template <typename T> add_method(T method)
{
  Methods.push_back(static_cast<Method>(method));
}
```

что избавит вас от необходимости делать явное приведение типа в наследниках. При этом ограничения самого `static_cast` проследят за правильностью типа передаваемого указателя.

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
class B;

class A
{
   using B_Method = void ( B::* )(Arg1 * arg1, Arg2 * arg2);
   std::vector<B_Method> m_methods;
   void DoSomething(int methodNo, Arg1 * arg1, Arg2 * arg2);
};

class B : public A
{
    B(void)
    {
       Methods.push_back(&B::Something);
    }

    void Something(Arg1* arg1, Arg2* arg2) { }
};

void A::DoSomething(int methodNo, Arg1 * arg1, Arg2 * arg2)
{
    (static_cast<B *>(this)->*(m_methods[methodNo]))(arg1, arg2);
}
```

Comment: А если родитель ничего не знает о потомке? Использовать шаблон?
Что бы вынести родителя в отдельную либу и использовать во множестве потомков, использующих изначальное АПИ в своих целях через хелперы родителя.

Как я понимаю указатель на функцию класса это некоторое смещение, раз так, то хотелось бы как-то подсунуть указатель базового класса через this (а мы точно уверены, что в runtime это будет наследник) и сделать смещение к функциям наследника?

Comment: @АндрейЖбанников Передача указателя на методы потомка в родительский класс и вызовы в нем этих методов подразумевает, что родительский класс знает о потомке. Иначе придется использовать какой-то промежуточный объект. Типа `std::function` вместо указателя на метод.

Comment: @VTT: Абсолютно не верно. Никакого знания у родителя о потомках не нужно (!). Указатели на методы в С++ **контравариантны**. Для преобразования к указателю на метод потомка нужен явный каст, но после этого все будет работать само по себе. Еще раз: никакого знания у родителя о потомках не нужно.